# How do I show whole numbers, not decimals, on a Core Plot Y axis?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I am plotting a line graph in using Core Plot and I want the Y axis labels to show as whole numbers. For example, my range is from 0 to 10 with an interval of 1, but the graph currently shows axis labels of 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and so on.

How do I make it so that Core Plot shows the labels as 1, 2, 3, and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `labelFormatter` (and `minorTickLabelFormatter` if you're labeling the minor ticks) property on the axis. These are standard [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects.

Answer (score 5):

i am just posting code here, i have same issues before and solved that but currently i forgot which change i have done so please review below code you will get exact solution what you want.

It's working fine just need to test using this...

```
NSNumberFormatter *yAxisFormat = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[yAxisFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle]; 

CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"20");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.title = @"Number of Cards Learned";
y.titleOffset = 45.0f;
y.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(50.0f);
y.labelFormatter = yAxisFormat;
```

if further issues then just inform me.

Comment: Thank you so much Neel  and Erick I just used the NSNumberFormatter  and set the y.labelFormatter to the specified NSFormatter object.

Comment: don't forgot to up vote whenever you have enough point(25)... also accept the answer too...