# How change precision of axis labels in CorePlot?

Tags: core-plot

When looking through code examples for CorePlot as well as the documentation, I can not find how to change (i.e. the property of the axis) the precision of the labels. I want to omit the decimals from the labels (i.e. not "500.0" but rather "500") as they are taking up precious space in my plot. Can someone guide me on this?

/Mikael

Comment: possible duplicate of [core plot:y-axis labels on line graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305276/core-ploty-axis-labels-on-line-graph)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNumberFormatter *Yformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[Yformatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
[Yformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
y.labelFormatter = Yformatter;
```

Add this block of code for either axis.

Comment: You might want to edit this to say ' call this block of code' or 'call this code' as this is not exactly a 'block' object.